# Which is the original source for the Augmented Dickey Fuller test?

Tags: time-series, references, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

### Which paper first introduces the Augmented Dickey Fuller (ADF) test?

- [Wikipedia does not mention any particular citations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Dickey%E2%80%93Fuller_test)
- [this paper (#1 on google scholar when searching for the test) does not mention a source for the test](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1911068)

Was it introduced in the [original paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1979.10482531)? I can not really see it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the original paper, you can get it on researchgate:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243644934_Distribution_of_the_Estimators_for_Autoregressive_Time_Series_With_a_Unit_Root

However, they do not call it Augmented Dickey Fuller Test by themselves, that would be a little egomaniac. If you search for a source which "named" it ADF then this might be not the real source. But it may be the source for invention of the test, as they deal clearly with stationarity and the search for a unit root and the respective hypotheses in the ADF-Test.

And this paper is also referred by statsmodels (python library for time series) in this paper:
So I believe you are on the right track.

This paper here highlights crictial thresholds for testa and also cites your resource.
https://www.econ.queensu.ca/sites/econ.queensu.ca/files/wpaper/qed_wp_1227.pdf